# Are there any containers running without namespaces and cgroups?

Tags: docker, containers, lxc, runc, rkt

Most container runtimes are based on namespaces and cgroups (docker, lxc, runc). I am wondering if there are on-the-market or open-source containers that are not based on these technologies ? Do you know some names ?

Answer (score 1):

Before the introduction of cgroups and namespaces, the isolation consisted to use *chroot()*. But this was insufficient from a security point of view. As only the file system was isolated. And it is possible to escape from a "chrooted" environment.

This [link](https://blog.aquasec.com/a-brief-history-of-containers-from-1970s-chroot-to-docker-2016) provides an history of the containerization techniques in the Unix/Linux world.

Comment: hmmm ok I see
The word "container" is rather general and does not mean something specific, I can chroot only and call it a container, and I can also use advanced isolations such as the ones we know nowadays with lxc and docker